# Compare two Dataframes of sentences and return a third one

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I want to compare two long Dataframe columns of sentences, and return a third dataframe that looks like this.
a snapshot is shown below.

My first approach was long winded and only worked for single instances, but failed when i applied it to the dataframe. It can be found in a previous question.

The logic is for words in c1 and c2, new value =1, for word in only c1, value set to zero.

```
sentences = tra_df['Sent1']
context = tra_df['Sent2']
```

```
Sent1[0] = "I am completely happy with the plan you have laid out today"
Sent2[0] = 'the plan you have laid out today'
c3 = ['0', '0', '0', '0' , '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

Comment: All I see are strings and lists, where is the dataframe?

Comment: it is in fact a dataframe, but i showed the string and list so as to show a snapshot of the type of data

Comment: @jorijinsmit I have clarified it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of your question, here is the solution.

```
def get_common_words(c1, c2):
    res = [0]*len(c1.split())
    for idx, existing_word in enumerate(c1.split()):
        if existing_word in c2.split():
            res[idx] = 1
    return res

get_common_words(c1, c2)
```

If you want to make it work for a pandas dataframe

```
def get_common_words_df(row):
   c1 = row['Sent1']
   c2 = row['Sent2']
   return get_common_words(c1, c2)


df['sent3'] = df.apply(get_common_words_df, axis=1)
```

You can optimize it a lot

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, but I don't quite understand how these two functions can work together. I have a DataFrame column of 3000 rows of Sent1 and Sent2, and i want to iterate over them without manually calling each row for the function

Comment: `apply` will do the same. Please look into the documentation

Comment: There is one more thing that this solution missed. The only parts of sent 1 that should be swapped is the exact chunk of phrase of sent 2. if i modify sent1 by adding  "I am  you have completely happy with the plan you have laid out today", the extra words i added turn up as '1' instead of '0'